# Which library can be used for parsing big xml files using css/xpath selectors in nodejs?

Tags: xml, node.js, sax

I love sax parser. But i have to handle nesting level while parsing my files.

I would much more usable to use css (or in worst way xpath) paths.

Could you please advise one?

I definitely don't want anything based on `node-expat`, and would like sax-based solutions. I'd write one, but it seems that there are a lot of similar solutions, but i can't find something really working in all nodejs' mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selector parser that work with data streams:

[html-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-select)

XPATH parsers based on SAX:

[saxtract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxtract)

[saxpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxpath)

Please note both of the libraries for xpath are not very tolerant for invalid xml in the parsed document.

Comment: I've tried `saxpath`, it seems to be working, but they have awful api. Other solutions seems to be interesting, thank you!